# Eliminar archivos con fs Node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, knex, fs

Hola amigos quiero sacar los nombres de los archivos de un objeto JSON que me devuelve knex y elimiarlos de mi servidor usando **fs**, esta es la idea que tengo de mi función.

```
const qu = knex().select('img1','img2','img3').from('NEWS_')
    .where('id',[id]);

    qu.then((data)=>{
        data.forEach((data)=>{
            console.log(data);

            fs.unlink('/uploads/'+data, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                // if no error, file has been deleted successfully
                console.log('File deleted!');
            });
        });
    });
```

obviamente me devuelve un error garrafál, porque le estoy pasando un objeto y no cada uno de los nombres de los archivos que vienen en ese objeto, alguien pdoría decirme como puedo acomodarlo para que funcione , quizá con un **for** ? aunque no estoy del todo seguro.

Este es el objeto que recibo

```
{ img1: '1ab886597057510d713f6e4c96ac0dc37c91.jpg',
  img2: '44387ef42839ac3764db6477a5cd15ebb493.jpg',
  img3: 'fe1b6c485056c82e00b58750b3047311fff0.jpg' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si, la solución es usar un bucle `for`. Además, si lo que recibes en `data` es un objeto como el que describes, el método `forEach()` no lo puedes aplicar allí, ya que es un método exclusivo del tipo `Array`.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea eliminar (*unlink*) ciertos archivos de un directorio, usando NodeJS. El nombre de los archivos a eliminar se obtienen de una consulta a una BD, la cual devuelve un objeto con la data solicitada.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para eliminar los archivos se usará el módulo [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) de NodeJS y un bucle `for...in` para recorrer el objeto y extraer el valor de los archivos. El método a usar será [`unlink()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback), el cual recibe como parámetros el nombre del archivo y una función callback que se ejecutará cuando se realice la operación. El método `unlink()` es un método asíncrono. Existe la versión sincrónica llamada [`unlinkSync()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlinksync_path). La diferencia (aparte de ser sincrónica) es que a esta última no se le pasa como argumento una función callback.

El código puede quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
const qu = knex().select('img1','img2','img3').from('NEWS_')
    .where('id',[id]);

qu.then((data) => {
    for(let key in data) {  // bucle "for in" para recorrer objetos
        fs.unlink('/uploads/' + data[key], (err) => {  // data[key] devuelve el valor del campo
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('File deleted: ' + data[key]);
        });
    }
});
```

Si los archivos existen en el directorio y el objeto `data` contiene los nombre correctos, todo debería funcionar.

Un ejemplo (sin borrar archivos) para mostrar la funcionalidad de `for ... in` sería:

```js
const objeto = {
  img1: '1ab886597057510d713f6e4c96ac0dc37c91.jpg',
  img2: '44387ef42839ac3764db6477a5cd15ebb493.jpg',
  img3: 'fe1b6c485056c82e00b58750b3047311fff0.jpg'
}

for(let key in objeto) {
    console.log('File deleted: ' + objeto[key]);
}
```

Espero que sea la respuesta que estabas buscando.

Answer (score 0):

simplemente quita el /

```
const qu = knex().select('img1','img2','img3').from('NEWS_')
    .where('id',[id]);

    qu.then((data)=>{
        data.forEach((data)=>{
            console.log(data);

            fs.unlink(`uploads/${data}`, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                // if no error, file has been deleted successfully
                console.log('File deleted!');
            });
        });
    });
```

O intentalo así te funcionará